# in huge/heavy/severe/great/___ jeopardy?

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjectives can be used to characterize jeopardy, as used in the phrase "in [some adjective] jeopardy"?

*This is not a homework problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of adjectives can precede jeopardy, according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grave%20jeopardy%2C%20big%20jeopardy%2Cserious%20jeopardy%2Cgreat%20jeopardy%2Cconsiderable%20jeopardy%2Csubstantial%20jeopardy%2Cterrible%20jeopardy&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrave%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserious%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsiderable%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubstantial%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cterrible%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0)

> ***Serious and great*** appear to be the more common

Comment: I would add ***grave*** to the list: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grave+jeopardy%2Cserious+jeopardy%2Cgreat+jeopardy%2Cconsiderable+jeopardy%2Csubstantial+jeopardy%2Cterrible+jeopardy&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrave%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserious%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsiderable%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubstantial%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cterrible%20jeopardy%3B%2Cc0)